# Restore Postgres database without pg_dump after OS reinstall?

Tags: postgresql, debian, pg-dump, pg-restore

I recently reinstalled the OS (Debian wheezy --> stretch) in which I was running a Postgres 9.3 database. The database itself was stored on a separate physical drive that was not formatted during the OS reinstall.

Foolishly, I didn't run a full pg_dump before changing OS.

Is there any way for me to restore the database from its raw form on the second hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is always a solution if the DB was not wiped. The data is still there.

I would make a copy of all of that data and install a 9.3 Server and exchange that Servers Directory with the saved Directory.

You could try to install Debian wheezy in a virtual machine and do there the copy and dump.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/storage-file-layout.html